# springboot tomcat deployment in amazon ec2 getting css and js 404 errors

Tags: spring, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I'm currently trying to deploy my web application through ec2 with tomcat.
It does work when i enter my ip and url but css and js is not working as below picture.
I'm using gradle build and intellij as an IDE. It works fine in external tomcat deployment. But when I try it in ec2 the css and js won't render.

[css, js 404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1byR.png)

my css and js files are structured as below picture

[css and js structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNWuR.png)

can anyone help me solve the problem?

Comment: Can you provide more details about your project: which build system are you using (Maven?), the IDE (Intellij?)… It seems that your are putting all static content into `src/main/resources/static`, instead of the web root `src/main/webapp`. Check [this tutorial](https://mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/)

Comment: sorry for short information Karwasz. I'm using gradle and intellij for IDE. Good tutorial but do u have one for gradle version?

Comment: The convention for the directory structure are the same in Maven and Gradle: `src/main/java` for the code, `src/main/resources` for the resources accessible from your code **only**, `src/main/webapp` for the resources accessible from the web.

Comment: Thx for the information!! Then wht do u suggest me to do. Should I make a webapp folder and move all css and js to that folder? Any tutorials?

Answer (score 1):

To work around the 404 error in your case, add `spring.resources.add-mappings=true` in your `.properties` configuration file. This tells Springboot to map whatever static files to `GET` API calls.

Another possibility is that the static files were not packaged in the first place. You can  enter the `.jar` package (which you deployed onto the remote server) and check if these files were included or not.

If not, re-run `mvn clean package` and check the static file inclusion again.

---

You should have posted the details, e.g., stacktrace, raw html.

Did you note the console error message, `Refused to apply style from ... because its MIME type application/json is not a supported...`? You specified the wrong MIME type (application/json) for stylesheet. The error has nothing to do with EC2 or Springboot. You need to correct the stylesheet references in html `<head>`.

Comment: I tried adding spring.resources.add-mappings=true but since it says it is deprecated i changed to spring.web.resources.add-mappings=true and also it doesn't work.. I checked the .jars they were packaged. It actually works fine when I deploy locally on external tomcat. But when I try it in ec2, css and js doesnt render...